# VBA - ArrayList - Get element at index

Tags: vba, arraylist

I am kind of new to **VBA** and I am stuck at the simple task of getting an element out of my **ArrayList** at a **spesified index**.

```
Set resultList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

resultList.Add element1
resultList.Add element2
resultList.Add element3
resultList.Add element4

return resultList.get(2)  '<-- Not working
```

I have checked the documentation of ArrayList but failed to find such a "get(index)" function:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `resultList(2)` will give you the third element

Comment: There is no legal `Return foo.bar` statement in VBA. If you're working in VB.NET, then why are you using `CreateObject` to create an `ArrayList`? Is your question tagged correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can legally use `return resultList.Item(2)` and have working code, then you're not using VBA but VB.NET.

> In VBA a function's return value needs to be assigned using the function's identifier:
>
> ```
> Public Function GetFoo() As String
>     GetFoo = "Hello"
> End Function
> ```
>
> In VB.NET a function's return value is returned using the `Return` keyword:
>
> ```
> Public Function GetFoo() As String
>     Return "Hello"
> End Function
> ```

And if you're using VB.NET, then you have absolutely no reason whatsoever to use `CreateObject` to create an `ArrayList`.

And if you're using .NET 2.0 or greater, you have absolutely zero reason to use an `ArrayList` anyway.

Use a generic `List(Of SomeType)` and enjoy type safety.

That said, `Item` is an `ArrayList`'s *default property*, so you could just as well do this:

```
Return resultList(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution myself:

```
resultList.Item(2)
```